# Connection reset error when I try to redeploy application to tomcat7 server

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7

My WAR is not very large, just 15MB.
I'm using tomcat7-maven-plugin for "redeploy" goal.
+ I'm using 80 port to request tomcat7.
Configuration saved in pom.xml and has the next view:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>       
                <url>http://<my ip>/manager</url>   
                <path>/<app name></path>                                
                <username>username</username>
                <password>password</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Maven trying to deploy 4 times and then goes with next message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) on project <app name>: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection reset
```

Earlier everything worked fine. Can it be server network connection issue? But for now all application that runs on tomcat working good. Or what else it can be?

EDIT: The reason was in lack of free space on device.

Comment: there is a limit for uploading files. Think you have to increase it, or your tomcat is down

Comment: What change did you make since it was last working? Are you able to re-start Tomcat or is that not an option?

Comment: Jens, I can deploy this application to other tomcat server, where I didn't change limit for uploading files.

Comment: Steve, server is a VM, so i installed open-vm-tools, but I installed this too on other server, where I can deploy after that. I tried to restart, it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

if there is no network problem then the cause of problem will show up at tomcat's log you should look there get real cause.